# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry"

Tags: iphone, ios, flurry

I am trying to integrate Flurry analytics 4.1.0 into my iPhone application, but I am receiving the following error when trying to build the project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
```

I have followed the Flurry steps and googled the issue but everyone with a similar issue had simply forgotten to link SystemConfiguration.framework.

Below are some screenshots of my project setup.

[image: project files]
[image: libraries]
[image: project build settings]

Comment: Might be some change recently, I don't need to do anything after adding `pod 'FlurrySDK', '5.0'` in my Podfile.

Comment: And if libflurry doenst appear in the list you can browse to the file and add it via that way (worked for me)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems that the library *libFlurry.a* isn't properly added to your project. It should appear in the second screenshot.

Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> icon at the bottom of the *Link Binary with Libraries* view (second screenshot) and select the *libFlurry.a* file. Then build again.

Comment: Note that if you are using CocoaPods you still need to manually add the lib.

Comment: For CocoaPods, you need to manually add the lib every time you update Pods.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, you also need add the following frameworks:

```
CFNetwork.framework
Security.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't see this anywhere in Flurry's docs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but my libFlurry.a file is located IN the pod folder named as "libFlurry_6.7.0.a". I am not sure whether I am being stupid here, but just in case someone like me don't know where to look for it...

After adding it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using flurry via pods:

```
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryAds'
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/TumblrAPI'
```

I had to link the libFlurryAds.a from the pods folder.

[image]